# Multiple mysql queries with Express Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am running an Express server and connecting to MySQL Database. I am have two tables  which are referenced via the `user_id`. When the user provides the email address I need to query `users` to find the `user_id` then run another query to join the `tracking` tables. What is the best way to achieve this? Also any best practice recommendations for any part of the code is appreciated!

Thanks

MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
  first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  date_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tracking (
  tracking_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  metric VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  unit VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  amount DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  date_tracked DATE,
  date_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (tracking_id),
  INDEX user_ind (user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
   REFERENCES users(user_id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Express (Nodejs)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var mysql = require("mysql");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  database: "tracker"
});

app.get("/data/:email/metric/:metric", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  let user_id = "";

  connection.connect();

  connection.query(
    `SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = '${req.params.email}';`,
    function(error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      user_id = results[0].user_id;
    }
  );

  connection.query(
    `SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email, tracking.metric, tracking.unit, tracking.amount, tracking.date_tracked FROM users JOIN tracking ON users.user_id = tracking.user_id WHERE users.user_id = '${user_id}' AND metric = '${
      req.params.metric
    }';`,
    function(error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send(results);
    }
  );

  connection.end();
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a single query, just `JOIN` the tables on `user_id`

```
SELECT 
  u.first_name, 
  u.last_name, 
  u.email, 
  t.metric, 
  t.unit, 
  t.amount, 
  t.date_tracked 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN tracking AS t ON t.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.email = '<email>' AND t.metric = '<metric>'
```

Also, FWIW you should use parameterised queries to protect yourself from SQL Injection

```
const values = [
  req.params.email, 
  req.params.metric
];
connection.query(
  'SELECT ... WHERE u.email = ? AND t.metric = ?', 
  values, 
  (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) return next(e); // propagate the error to Express, rather than throwing in the callback

    res.send(results);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to query users to find the user_id then run another query to join the tracking tables. What is the best way to achieve this?

You can achieve it with only 1 query:

```
    SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email, 
            tracking.metric, tracking.unit, tracking.amount,
            tracking.date_tracked 
    FROM users 
    JOIN tracking 
    ON users.user_id = tracking.user_id 
    WHERE users.email = '${req.params.email}' AND 
          metric = '${req.params.metric}
```

> Also any best practice recommendations for any part of the code is appreciated!

First of all, you should connect to mySql after the server as started .

Connecting&Disconnecting on each request will impact the performance(It's expensive task opening a socket and connecting outside)

so try something like :

```
    CONNECTION.connect().then(() => {
        // mysql is ready , let's start express server 
        // accepting connections
        app.listen(port, () => console.log(`ready on ${port}!`));
    }).catch(console.error)
```

Another good practice you should know is running queries in parallel
with Promise.all([]). when you need to run multiple , unrelated queries , 
you can Execute them all one after the other , making the **total** wait time for all results much smaller .